# C# Roslyn Deleting/Modifing SyntaxNodes

Tags: c#, roslyn, csharpcodeprovider

I am trying to delete spesific nodes from Syntax tree but it throws this exception: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name' (3rd Line in the code)

```
var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(textFile);
var root = syntaxTree.GetRoot();
root = root.RemoveNodes(root.DescendantNodes()
.Where(node => node.ChildTokens()
.Any(token => token.ValueText == "Test")), SyntaxRemoveOptions.KeepNoTrivia);
```

Tried using TrackedNodes but could not get it to work, all the examples seems to be outdated.
How should I delete or modify nodes?

Comment: Can you point to a specific line that this exception is thrown at?

Comment: Also the stack trace would be helpful.